# How do I disable an <HTML:submit> button without disabling the associated form?

Tags: java, jsp, struts

I have users that like to rapidly click on the submit button when they're being impatient, and this can cause the associated action to submit multiple times.  What I want to do is disable the button on click like so:

```
<htmt:submit property="submitFunction" value="<℅WorkForm.SUBMIT_REGULAR %>" styleClass="button" onclick="this.disabled=true;/>
```

This disables the button, but also prevents it from submitting its form data, because it relies on knowing whether SUBMIT_REGULAR or another submit type is being used.

How can I disable this button without also disabling the form?

Comment: Try onSubmit="document.getElementById('YOUR_SUBMIT_BUTTON_ID').disabled=true;" istead of using onclick function

Comment: first you disable a button, then doing submit or vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

**Simplest solution**
just write **`return false;`** inside onclick event.

**`<htmt:submit property="submitFunction" value="<℅WorkForm.SUBMIT_REGULAR %>" styleClass="button" onclick="return false;"/>`**